# Probability that Greatest Integer Function can be Split

Tags: probability

I'm having some trouble with this question, any help would be appreciated. For some given $n$, what is the probability that $$\left\lfloor\frac{a+b}{n}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{a}{n}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{b}{n}\right\rfloor?$$

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$? And what can $n$ be? How is $n$ chosen? You can't say that $n$ is a random real number or random integer, because those terms are not well defined (there are no [uniform distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution) on $\mathbb{R}$ or on $\mathbb{Z}$) ...

Answer (score 0):

Put $\frac{a}{n} = \left\lfloor \frac{a}{n} \right\rfloor+\varepsilon$ and $\frac{b}{n} = \left\lfloor \frac{b}{n} \right\rfloor+\eta$, with $\varepsilon \in [0,1)$ and $\eta \in [0,1)$. Then:
$$
\left\lfloor \frac{a}{n}+\frac{b}{n} \right\rfloor=\left\lfloor \left\lfloor\frac{a}{n}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{b}{n}\right\rfloor+\varepsilon+\eta \right\rfloor=\left\lfloor \left\lfloor\frac{a}{n}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{b}{n}\right\rfloor \right\rfloor
$$
if and only if $\varepsilon+\eta\in [0,1)$.

Now the question is a bit vague, but I assume we are supposed to assume that $\varepsilon \sim U([0,1))$, $\eta \sim U([0,1))$ and are independent, in which case the probability that $\varepsilon+\eta\in [0,1)$ is $1/2$